Entity Framework not loading navigation property when included
List<Message> messages = context.Messages
   .Include(message => message.User)
   .ToList();

// Comment / uncomment this code
User w = context.Users.FirstOrDefault();

Message class
public partial class Message 
{
   public Guid UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;
}

User class
public partial class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new List<Message>();
}

OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>(entity =>
{
   entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Messages).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
}

I need an explanation for the EF behaviour.
When the code is commented, the messages list receives messages without the User (user == null).

However, when the code runs with both statements, the messages list returns the User object.

Eventhough this is eager loading, i thought about EF not wanting to go to the Users table until needed but when i try to access the messages[0].User, it returns null as well.
Thank you.
EntityFramework 6.4.4
EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.3

Let me get this straight!! What you're saying is that at the messages object won't include x=> x.User if you don't include the w object in your code!? Could you add a screenshot of your quick watch here please!? I don't see how those objects related to one and other.
Also, add the code snipit for your entities here as well. The entities should include both the Message and User classes as well as how they're related to one & other.

Updated the post, included all of the important informations - can't share the whole code since its work related

You're are configuring the MessageSchedule entity via modelBuilder.Entity<MessageSchedule>(entity => ...; shouldn't that be for the Message via modelBuilder.Entity<Message>(....?

I'm with @pfx on this. Your code doesn't paint the full picture in this question. You're defining your entity as Message but configuring it under MessageSchedule

This won't repro for me.  If you can provide a short, complete repro that demonstrates the issue, add it to your question.

It is for Message, i just tried to change the name of the classes so that people at my work don't bother me about it.

Remove = null!;.
